# Error while trying to pull azure key vault from azure function - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: authKeyOrResourceToken

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-keyvault

I want to integrate my azure functions app with the key vault. I followed the steps shown here http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/benjarvis/post/Azure-Functions-Key-Vault-Integration

But facing this error- Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: authKeyOrResourceToken

Not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to add an environmental variable named 'authKeyOrResourceToken' under the application settings, proving the value with default func key. But no luck.

This is how my function.json looks like

{
      "type": "CosmosDB",
      "name": "<>",
      "databaseName": "<>",
      "collectionName": "<>",
      "connectionStringSetting": "<>",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c where c.recordType = {recordType}",
      "direction": "in"
    }

While I expect the result of the query, I'm facing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working.

I was writing Azure Function using Node.js. So from this function, if I need to access the key vault, it is expected to install 2 npm modules (azure-keyvault & ms-rest-azure). Once installed, I was able to access the key vault.

Ironically, there is no such dependency for Azure functions written in .net. It works out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

`connectionStringSetting` should have, as value, the **name of a setting** in your Function App that has a value in the format:

`@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=secret_uri_with_version)`

Where *secret_uri_with_version* is the secret url that contains your **Cosmos DB Connection String** (full connection string, not just the key).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, Matias. I did keep the secret url in the above format in an application setting and gave the name of that setting as a value for connectionStringSetting. But still facing the same issue.
Here is how I gave it in application setting -
topsecret : @Microsoft.keyVault(secretUri=<mysecreturl>)

and in function.json
"connectionStringSetting" : "topsecret"

But still the issue. Any thing I'm missing here?

Comment: Honestly it should work, I have used it in many demos in the past and it always worked. Two more things: Are you running on Functions V2? And, I'm not sure, but your `@Microsoft.keyValue....` has the `k` lower-case, did you try with the correct casing? Also with `secretUri` and `SecretUri`. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, my func app is running on v2. And also, I'm using the correct casing. Might be my typo earlier in the comment but yes, I've checked it again. No issues with the casing. I've registered the func app with key vault app. Apart from this, do I need to do anything?

Comment: No, that should be it. Have you tried with the plain Connection String instead of the Key Vault Url to rule out some permission issue? Connection String should be in a format like `AccountEndpoint=https://<your-account-name>.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=<your-key>;`

Comment: Yes, I tried that. And I'm able to access the data with plain connection string. Also, I gave the permission to the functions app to access the key vault. So will there be any other permission required?

Comment: Not that I know of, what you could try to see if it's being resolved correctly: Add a new setting that accesses the KeyVault secret, then within one Function, read that with `process.env["yournewsettingname"]` and see if it resolves to the correct connection string. If it doesn't then someone is wrong with the permissions.